# convert number 123 which is a time 1:23 into msec

Tags: r, time, milliseconds

I am reading in an excel spreadsheet into a data frame. The time was coded as a number with no punctuation, so 123 means 1:23 (1 minute and 23 seconds), and 23 means 23 seconds, 524 means 5:24 etc.

So, this numer is a column in the data frame. I want to calculate a new column that converts these numbers into msec. I've tried a bunch of different things, e.g, this function:

```
# function to convert time into msecseconds
toMSec <- function(x){
a = as.numeric(str_sub(as.character(x), -2, -1))*1000
b = as.numeric(str_sub(as.character(x), -4, -3))*1000*60
if (any(is.na(b))){ b = 0}
y = a+b

# return the correct number of msec
return(y)

}
```

But the b part of the function fails, and I just get the answer for the seconds portion. I seem to be running into an issue with the need to have a vectorized answer, so I can apply the function to the entire column of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm getting what you're asking for correctly:

```
toMSec<- function(x) (x%/%100*60+x%%100)*1000
```

Explanation: `toMSec` takes the number mmss, uses %/% (quotient) to get the minutes, times 60 to get seconds, and adds to that the remainder (%% - modulo) to get the seconds. The whole thing is multiplied by 1000 to get milliseconds.